# Magento: get price in current currency

Tags: magento

I am having an extension that shows the products on main page in tabs. It uses the following code to get the price of product

`$price = $_product->getPrice();`

and then uses the following code to display it

`echo '<span class="price">'.number_format($price,2).'</span>'`

It works OK on the base currency but when another currency is selected it will not convert the price to that currency.

How can I show the price in current currency instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

```
$price = number_format($price,2);

$formatedPrice = Mage::helper('core')->currency($price, true, false);

echo '<span class="price">'.$formatedPrice.'</span>'
```